# How to fetch span class value using Selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium with java and want to fetch the value "3". I guess I have to use xpath but I am not sure what would be the syntax for that? the html code is given below:

```
<div class="p-panel halign-center">
  <div>
    <span class="p-text p-f-sz-xl p-t-secondary50  p-f-w-b p-t-wr-fw" data-tag="Transcript-Summary-No-Due-Date-Count">3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a more html structure? I can create XPath for given HTML but not sure whether it will be unique or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch value 3 by following code

```
String value = driver.findElement(by.xpath("//span[@data-tag='Transcript-Summary-No-Due-Date-Count']").getText();
```

OR

```
String value = driver.findElement(by.xpath("//span[@class='p-text p-f-sz-xl p-t-secondary50  p-f-w-b p-t-wr-fw']").getText();
```

Also we can improve the xpath if more HTML code is available.

Happy coding~

Comment: Below code is working for me... thanks:                                                                                                      
String value = (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@data-tag='Transcript-Summary-No-Due-Date-Count']")).getText());

Comment: String value = (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@data-tag='Transcript-Summary-No-Due-Date-Count']")).getText());

Comment: Glad to hear that :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is for getting by class:

```
.//span[@class='p-text p-f-sz-xl p-t-secondary50  p-f-w-b p-t-wr-fw']
```

This is for getting by text:

```
.//span[text()='3']
```

and this is both

```
.//span[@class='p-text p-f-sz-xl p-t-secondary50  p-f-w-b p-t-wr-fw' and text()='3']
```